# Multiple mutable borrows in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm playing around with building a very simple stack based evaluator in Rust. I want the user to be able to define functions later, so I'm storing all operators in a HashMap with closures as values.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub type Value = i32;

pub struct Evaluator<'a> {
    stack: Vec<Value>,
    ops: HashMap<String, &'a dyn FnMut(&'a mut Vec<Value>)>,
}

impl<'a> Evaluator<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Evaluator<'a> {
        let stack: Vec<Value> = vec![];
        let mut ops: HashMap<String, &'a dyn FnMut(&'a mut Vec<Value>)> = HashMap::new();

        ops.insert("+".to_string(), &|stack: &'a mut Vec<Value>| {
            if let (Some(x), Some(y)) = (stack.pop(), stack.pop()) {
                stack.push(y + x);
            }
        });

        Evaluator { stack, ops }
    }

    pub fn stack(&self) -> &[Value] {
        &self.stack
    }

    pub fn eval(&'a mut self, input: &str) {
        let symbols = input
            .split_ascii_whitespace()
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
        for sym in symbols {
            if let Ok(n) = sym.parse::<i32>() {
                self.stack.push(n);
            } else {
                let s = sym.to_ascii_lowercase();
                if let Some(f) = self.ops.get(&s) {
                    f(&mut self.stack);
                } else {
                    println!("error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut e = Evaluator::new();
    e.eval("1 2 +")
}
```

I'm currently getting two errors:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.stack` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/sample.rs:34:17
   |
10 | impl<'a> Evaluator<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
34 |                 self.stack.push(n);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
38 |                     f(&mut self.stack);
   |                     ------------------
   |                     | |
   |                     | first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                     argument requires that `self.stack` is borrowed for `'a`

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `**f` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/sample.rs:38:21
   |
38 |                     f(&mut self.stack);
   |                     ^ cannot borrow as mutable

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.stack` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/sample.rs:38:23
   |
10 | impl<'a> Evaluator<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
38 |                     f(&mut self.stack);
   |                     --^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |                     | |
   |                     | `self.stack` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
   |                     argument requires that `self.stack` is borrowed for `'a`

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0499, E0596.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
```

My concern is the first one. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I'm not borrowing them at the same time. Can I tell Rust the previous borrow (`self.stack.pop()`) is done? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my problem. The thing I kept coming back to is, "What owns the closures?" In this case I'm using references, but nothing is taking ownership of the data. When I refactored (below) with `Box` to take ownership, it worked.

I'm curious if there is a way to do this with with just references and/or if my explanation is wrong?

Working code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub type Value = i32;

pub struct Evaluator {
    stack: Vec<Value>,
    ops: HashMap<String, Box<dyn FnMut(&mut Vec<Value>)>>,
}

impl Evaluator {
    pub fn new() -> Evaluator {
        let stack: Vec<Value> = vec![];
        let mut ops: HashMap<String, Box<dyn FnMut(&mut Vec<Value>)>> = HashMap::new();

        ops.insert("+".to_string(), Box::new(|stack: &mut Vec<Value>| {
            if let (Some(x), Some(y)) = (stack.pop(), stack.pop()) {
                stack.push(y + x);
            }
        }));

        Evaluator { stack, ops }
    }

    pub fn stack(&self) -> &[Value] {
        &self.stack
    }

    pub fn eval(&mut self, input: &str) {
        let symbols = input
            .split_ascii_whitespace()
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
        for sym in symbols {
            if let Ok(n) = sym.parse::<i32>() {
                self.stack.push(n);
            } else {
                let s = sym.to_ascii_lowercase();
                if let Some(f) = self.ops.get_mut(&s) {
                    f(&mut self.stack);
                } else {
                    println!("error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut e = Evaluator::new();
    e.eval("1 2 +")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have borrows with conflicting lifetimes:

- You are defining a lifetime `'a` for the struct in line 5: `pub struct Evaluator<'a> {`
- In line 7, you are stating that `ops` is a `HashMap` that holds functions that receive mutable borrows for the whole duration of `'a`
- Then, in line 28, you are defining an `eval` method that holds a mutable reference to `self` for the whole duration of the struct `('a)`

The conflict can be solved if you use two different lifetimes, since the time that an operation borrows `self` should be inherently shorter than the lifetime for the whole evaluation, since in `eval` you are running a loop and multiple invocations to the operations.

This should fix the issues mentioned above:

```
pub struct Evaluator<'a, 'b> {
    stack: Vec<Value>,
    ops: HashMap<String, &'b dyn FnMut(&'b mut Vec<Value>)>,
}

impl<'a, 'b> Evaluator<'a, 'b> {
    pub fn new() -> Evaluator<'a> {
        let stack: Vec<Value> = vec![];
        let mut ops: HashMap<String, &'b dyn FnMut(&'b mut Vec<Value>)> = HashMap::new();
```